# Substring build in iteration loop based on delimiters

Tags: c#, delimiter

I'm pretty new to `C#` and having trouble.

I have this string with a '/'- delimiter: `"1/2/10/4"`

The string I need to use while I'm iterating through the loop should look like this:

```
i = 1; "1"
i = 2; "1/2"
i = 3; "1/2/10"
i = 4; "1/2/10/4"
```

Somehow it should be integrated here, but I don't know how:

```
        var IDArray = Convert.ToString(NodesID).Split('/');
        for (int i = 0; i < Convert.ToString(NodesID).Count(x => x == '/')+2; i++)
        {
            string IDCheck = IDArray[i];
            string ???
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I've edited your question a bit and added the C# tag. In general you should almost always add the tag of the language you're using. Tags help the right people see your question so that it can get answered quicker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var IDArray = Convert.ToString(NodesID).Split('/');
var builder = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < IDArray.Length; i++)
{
    builder.Append(IDArray[i]);
    var stringToUse = builder.ToString();

    //...
    //Use the stringToUse here. It contains exactly what you want.
    //...

    builder.Append("/");
}
```

Everything is self-explanatory. Let me know if there's something you didn't quite understand (or if I failed to correctly interpret your question).

Comment: Why not just update your answer? As it stands, the code won't even compile.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a helper method that will yield all of the subpaths you're looking for. Something like this should work:

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetSubPaths(string s)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i < s.Length; s++)
    {
        if(s[i] == '\\')
            yield return sb.ToString();
        sb.Append(s[i]);
    }
    yield return sb.ToString();
}
```

This method uses a C# trick called `yield return` which causes it to return an `IEnumerable<>` where each element is based on what's provided to `yield return`. So the elements in this returned `IEnumerable<>` will represent each substring group that you're describing.

Then you can use the results from this method however you want:

```
var subPaths = GetSubPaths("1/2/10/4").ToList();
for(int i = 0; i < subPaths.Count; i++)
{
    Console.Write("i = " + i + "; ");
    Console.WriteLine(subPaths[i]);
}
```

Comment: I tried your code and that string is correctly built through the iteration. Great! But what doesn't return the correct value is IDCheck = IDArray[i]; I retrieve from the delimiter Input-String in that same loop " for(int i = 0; i < subPaths.Count; i++)" Whatever I try the value is: System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label but not the content!

Comment: I solved the problem with the String that was assigned badly. BUT in the end I had problems with array dimension that was calculated badly. Therefore the loops weren't iterated correctly... I tried the code that "displayName" was proposing and it worked immediately. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly the most readable code, but a linqy solution would be:

```
var list = YourInput.Split('/').Aggregate(new List<string>(), (l, el) => { l.Add(l.Count == 0 ? el : l[l.Count - 1] + "/" + el); return l; });
```

This would create a list with the strings.

Comment: PS, Although a valid working solution, this answer is more for showing the possibility with linq than creating something that's easy for the eye. StriplingWarrior's code is much better in that aspect ;) If using Aggregate, theoretically you could even use it directly with previous and current (no list) and do your thing inside the aggregation action, but for maintainability that would be a rather poor approach.